# Importing Dexie in Service Worker

Tags: service-worker, dexie

is it possible to import Dexie in service worker?
`importScripts("https://unpkg.com/dexie@latest/dist/dexie.js");`

resulted in :
The script resource is behind a redirect, which is disallowed.
I've to import it locally to the worker by saving the code into a local file, but got a "window is undefined error"
although the Dexie code seems to check for self instead of window...

Am I missing something?
{`typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window :global;`}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

URLs passed in to `importScripts()` can't result in HTTP redirections. They [must return](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#importscripts) responses with the correct JavaScript MIME type, and with a `ok` (2xx) status code.

Requesting `https://unpkg.com/dexie@latest/dist/dexie.js` results in an HTTP redirection to `https://unpkg.com/dexie@2.0.3/dist/dexie.js`.

You should be able to import Dexie if you use the final, redirected URL:

```
importScripts('https://unpkg.com/dexie@2.0.3/dist/dexie.js');
```