# Service worker, caching a graph query request

Tags: graphql, service-worker

so I'm getting in the world of service workers, found it complex for my level, and despite I manage to cache my physical files in my vue 3 project. I'm struggling with the way of caching the response from headless CMS, there is a lot information around about in general most of then very old, at the beginning I tried using workbox, then I read that you cannot catch graph response or post response(correct if I am wrong), in addition I was having a lot of issues trying to include the script with the vue 3 project and some error about some array, so ended up building the sw from scratch and it worker pretty well so far. Now I'm facing the issue with the graph response, so far I have read it's not easy which is quite discouraging when u read it from more experienced people. I have found some examples and lot of user asking the same question here some with no response as well, and so far I found an interesting response(3 years old), however I am not sure if this actually applies for my case if is deprecate. He provides a code example, however is not providing information about what exactly does the script, you can see the response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35270702/can-service-workers-cache-post-requests)

So I am assuming the URL that needs to be provide is the url to my graph API in this case the one provide for CMS. And the in the variable cachedResponse under the catch, do I need to provide the query variable, meaning the const that I am using to call the graph? I have to mention I am not using apollo nor axios just a normal graph inclusion.

Also when I tried to run this code, at the beginning I got an issue with the script from dexie.js and had mime issue which I tried to correct with some suggestion [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50471617/importing-dexie-in-service-worker). Which did not work for me. I thought that was my sw cache playing bad, however I cleaned it got same issue.

So so far have been a long way, It seems there is not magic formula, but if I can receive an advice or different approach from what I have been trying so far, would be very welcome. Thank you in advance for the help : )